# Backtracing with no_std in rust

Tags: rust, osdev, backtrace

I am writing an operation system and I would like my OS to be able to generate nice backtraces, so that I can debug panics better. I wrote some code based on the [OSDev wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/Stack_Trace), but rust uses a completly different ABI, so that code doesn't seem to work. My code:

```
pub fn get_backtrace(mxf: u64) -> Vec<VirtAddr> {
    let mut ptr: *mut stackframe;
    unsafe {
        asm!(
            "mov {0}, rbp",
            out(reg) ptr
        );
    }
    let mut v: Vec<VirtAddr> = vec![];
    for _i in 0..mxf {
        let cf = unsafe { ptr.as_ref().expect("Error backtracing") };
        println!("Frame: {:?}", cf);
        v.push(VirtAddr::from_ptr(cf.rip as *const ()));
        ptr = cf.rbp as *mut stackframe;
        if ptr as u64 == 0 {
            break;
        }
    }
    v
}
```

I also got disassembly for some functions:

```
pwndbg> disassemble 'an_os::backtrace::addrof'
Dump of assembler code for function an_os::backtrace::addrof:
   0x0000000000229d80 <+0>:     sub    rsp,0x18
   0x0000000000229d84 <+4>:     mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x10],rdi
   0x0000000000229d89 <+9>:     call   0x221f90 <x86_64::addr::VirtAddr::from_ptr>
   0x0000000000229d8e <+14>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8],rax
   0x0000000000229d93 <+19>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8]
   0x0000000000229d98 <+24>:    add    rsp,0x18
   0x0000000000229d9c <+28>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
pwndbg> disassemble 'an_os::backtrace::mark'
Dump of assembler code for function an_os::backtrace::mark:
   0x000000000021b610 <+0>:     sub    rsp,0x38
   0x000000000021b614 <+4>:     mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x20],rdi
   0x000000000021b619 <+9>:     mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x28],rsi
   0x000000000021b61e <+14>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x30],rdx
   0x000000000021b623 <+19>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x18],rdx
   0x000000000021b628 <+24>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x10],rsi
   0x000000000021b62d <+29>:    call   0x229d80 <an_os::backtrace::addrof>
   0x000000000021b632 <+34>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8],rax
   0x000000000021b637 <+39>:    mov    rdi,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8]
   0x000000000021b63c <+44>:    mov    rsi,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x10]
   0x000000000021b641 <+49>:    mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x18]
   0x000000000021b646 <+54>:    call   0x21b110 <an_os::backtrace::markll>
   0x000000000021b64b <+59>:    add    rsp,0x38
   0x000000000021b64f <+63>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

How would one write a stack trace printer in that case?